# Can Google Analytics pull historical data?

Tags: google-analytics, confluence

Trying to dig in to GA here. I have a site built on a wiki platform (confluence) that has not had any GA setup prior. Trying to see if I could do something crafty with the GAPI to pull historical data as the site has been up for some ~3 years.

Is there any way to pull data if GA was not set up on any of the pages, or am I SOL? Took a gander at https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference but didn't see a clear answer

Answer (score 0):

I have only used Google Analytics to track data as it comes in.  If you have the historical data stored somewhere, you could probably write a script to iterate over the standard ga script and send off trackpageviews with the data you want, but unless you or someone else actually have the usage data tracked somewhere, you won't be able to materialize it out of thin air.